# Does gorm shares an ID from previous transaction Create

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a query, that requires ID from the previous insert. Does gorm gives away the ID in transaction mode:

Example:

```
err := db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    if err := tx.Model(&model.user).Create(&user).Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
    }

    // if user inserted get the user ID from previous user insert of DB 
    for _, v := profiles {
        v.UserID = user.ID // Can I get this ID from previous Create operation?
    }
    if err := tx.Model(&model.profile).Create(&profiles).Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
    }
})
```

Comment: Seems like you say https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Create-Record `user.ID             // returns inserted data's primary key`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Find function toget the data that you created.

```
if err := tx.Model(&model.profile).Create(&profiles).Find(&profiles).Error; err != nil {
     tx.Rollback()
}
```